# Retrieving and displaying PDF document from MySql / Java

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am trying to save PDF generated by my Java program into Mysql data base and trying to retrieve / display the same inside Java program. Following code has what I have done so far,

```
public class Save_PDFimage extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private ImageIcon format = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    PreparedStatement pst=null;
    //String filename = "C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\n.png";
    String filename = "C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\in.pdf";
    int s = 0;
    byte[] person_image = null;

private void Save_DBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
    File image = new File(filename);
    FileImageInputStream FIS = new FileImageInputStream(image);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    for(int readNum; (readNum=FIS.read(buf))!=-1;) {
    bos.write(buf,0,readNum);
    }
    person_image = bos.toByteArray();
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

    try {
    String sql = "Insert into invoices (Pdfs, Invoice_no_R) values(?,?)";
    String i= "1";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setBytes(1, person_image);
    pst.setString(2, i);
    pst.execute();
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    }

// Code for displaying the retrieved PDF in a jLabel

   private void Show_imageActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        String sql = "select Pdfs from invoices where Invoice_no_R = 1";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next())
        {
        byte[] Imagedata = rs.getBytes("Pdfs");
        format = new ImageIcon(Imagedata);
        jLabel1.setIcon(format);
        }
    } catch(Exception e ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } }
```

I am able to save PDF in but program doesn't display image after retrieving, the same logic works fine for a PNG/JPG file.

Please help...

Ramesh

Comment: You can try [pdfOne](http://code.google.com/p/pdfonejava/) it has a jar download to convert PDF to JPEG if GPL license is ok for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am trying to work out that option now. Will update you if it served my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

pdf is not an image format - it is a binary format. 
You cannot set it as icon to your imageicon.

Comment: hmm, what could be a suitable approach to get around this then??

Comment: depends on what you are trying to do? Do you need to set a pdf image as a button icon? then you need to get an PDF image (just google for it or get it from adobe.com) - once you have it, set it just like any other png/jpg.